# World to Pixel Transformation

Tags: 2d, xna-4.0, transformation

My objects have a location in world coordinates (basically 1.0f is a meter).
If I simply draw my objects using their world coordinates, each meter will correspond to a pixel. Obviously that's not what I want.

Now, I don't want to have to apply a transformation to each and every object's position when I draw them. As I happen to be using XNA, and spritebatch allows a Matrix to be passed in as an argument in it's begin method, I was wondering if there is a way to pass the World to Pixel transformation in there. Any suggestions?

So far Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(zoom, zoom, 1)) puts the objects in their proper spot, but it also scales up the sprites. Is there a way to transform the position without enlarging the sprite?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a value below 1 but above zero for `zoom`? Something like `1/zoom` is probably what you want. (edit: damnit why do old Questions keep popping up in my Question feed, sorry for bumping)